# awk: find multiple string and print out

Tags: bash, awk

I want to print out the line which contains "number" and lines between "start" and "end" in my input file and print out on the same output file.

I wrote that code

```
awk -v string="number" '$0~string' Input >> Output
awk ' /start/ {flag=1;next} /end/{flag=0} flag { print $0}' Input >> Output
```

However, it gave me that output and that is not what I really want

```
number 1
number 2
start
line 7
line 8
line 9
end
start
line 14
line 15
line 16
end
```

What I want is though

inputdata:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
number 1
line 4
line 5
line6
start
line 7
line 8
line 9
end
line 10
number 2
line 11
line 12
line 13
start
line 14
line 15
line 16
end
```

output:

```
number 1
start
line 7
line 8
line 9
end
number 2
start
line 14
line 15
line 16
end
```

Comment: The script you posted will not produce the output you say it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, this will avoid printing string `number` 2 times in case it is coming in between `start` and `end` too.

```
awk '/start/,/end/{print;next}; /number/'  Input_file
```

Let's say following is Input_file(I added a small editing in it by adding a string `number` in it).

```
cat Input_file
line 1
line 2
line 3
number 1
line 4
line 5
line6
start
line 7
line 8
line 9
end
line 10
number 2
line 11
line 12
line 13
start
line 14
number 13
line 15
line 16
end


awk '/start/,/end/{print;next}; /number/'  Input_file
number 1
start
line 7
line 8
line 9
end
number 2
start
line 14
number 13
line 15
line 16
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let's say I also want to change the name "number" with something else on the output file.

Comment: @usermrt, try this then and let me know `awk '/start/,/end/{print;next}; /number/{sub("number","new_thing_by_OP");print}'  Input_file` ?

Comment: @usermrt, np, glad that it helped you.

Comment: `/number/{sub("number","new_thing_by_OP");print}` = `sub(/number/,"new_thing_by_OP")`

Comment: !/bin/bash
defdatano=6

    for datano in $(eval seq 0 1 $(($defdatano - 1)))
    do {
      echo $datano
      awk '/#DATA'$(($datano - 1))'/,/#END/{print;next}; /#AUTHORS/ { sub ("#AUTHORS" , "s'$datano' "); print}'  DataInput >> DataOutput
    } done

Comment: Would you take a look at this? How can I prevent "for statement" to print out 7 times before data?

Comment: @usermrt, looks like different question, request you to open new post too on this.

Comment: I did. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 4):

In awk:

```
$ awk '/number/;/start/,/end/' file
```

Output:

```
number 1
start
line 7
line 8
line 9
end
number 2
start
line 14
line 15
line 16
end
```

There is a problem in the solution, however. If there is `number` inside the start-end block, it gets printed out twice. If that is the case with the data, @Ravinder's solution is the fix.

Comment: I knew the `sed` form of this but just learned a new `awk` trick. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using sed

```
sed -n '/number/p;/start/,/end/p' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd never use a range expression as it makes code for trivial things very slightly briefer but then requires a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions when your requirements change. I'd always just use a flag instead:

```
$ awk '/start/{f=1} f || /number/{print} /end/{f=0}' file
number 1
start
line 7
line 8
line 9
end
number 2
start
line 14
line 15
line 16
end
```

The `f` is for `found`, not for `flag` - a flag is the type of the variable, found is what it means. wrt changing number to something else, here's 1 interpretation of what you might mean by that:

```
$ awk '/start/{f=1} f || sub(/number/,"foobar"){print} /end/{f=0}' file
foobar 1
start
line 7
line 8
line 9
end
foobar 2
start
line 14
line 15
line 16
end
```